# What's the right way to use git filter-branch directory option?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use git filter-branch with `-d` option, but not sure what value to use. I tried `git filter-branch -d /tmp` and also the output of `mktemp -d`, but both result in the error "... already exists, please remove it".

What's the right way to use this?

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#git-filter-branch--f

> `git filter-branch` refuses to start with an existing temporary directory

So either pass a non-existing directory to `-d` or use `-d` with `-f/--force`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the name of a directory that does not exist.  Git will *create* it.  The process of creating it will guarantee that the newly-created temporary directory is empty, which means that `git filter-branch` will be able to operate correctly.

Note that when `filter-branch` does use the directory, it also creates several sub-directories within the directory.  If you are using `--tree-filter`, the temporary tree directory is a sub-directory of the `-d` argument you supplied.

(It's possible to use `-d` with `-f`, as in [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54192615/1256452), but then this will also run even if you already have a non-empty `refs/original/` name-space, which is not necessarily a good idea.  You will know if it is a good idea, but if you know that, you will also understand the `-d` option and not be asking this question. :-) )

Comment: I thought the whole point of `-d` was to use the OS's temp directories, because of some performance benefits? The docs say "Use this option to set the path to **the temporary directory** used for rewriting." (emphasis mine). I assumed this meant that `/tmp` has some OS related performance benefits that are somehow different from `~/Desktop` for example. How is specifing `-d` with any random directory useful at all?

Comment: @mehulkar: suppose you have, on Linux, mounted a memory-based file system in `/a`.  Then `git filter-branch -d /a/fb.$$ ...` will `mkdir` `/a/fb.<pid>` in which to do its work. Being a memory file system, this will run as fast as possible, given that you're using file-system operations. (If you don't supply `-d` Git uses `.git/<something>` as the temporary directory.) I'm not sure if OS X has a memory file system, and if not, there is little use for `-d`.